# Algorithm used to prevent a player from getting their same card

Tags: sorting, lua, tabletop-simulator

I have a game I am coding in Tabletop Simulator where all players (P) is given a card (C). Once memorized all players put the card back into the deck (D), shuffled, and then all players are dealt one of the cards from the same deck (D). I am trying to code the simplest algorithm that prevents a player from getting their own card. Now when it comes to coding this should be simple I assume instead of creating simulations to run until it is successful.

Comment: I know I can do it that way, but this is done via code so I wanted to make it as simple as possible. If there was a simple way to do it, I would like it done that way if possible.

Comment: How would you do this with a real deck of cards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have the following:

- `deck`, a randomized deck containing all the cards (including those the players have seen).
- `seen_card_id_by_player`, a lookup table that give you the guid of the card a player has seen.

Then the solution is simply

```lua
local card_ids = {}
for i, card_data in ipairs(deck.getObjects()) do
   table.insert(card_ids, card_data.guid)
end

for player, seen_card_id in pairs(seen_card_id_by_player) do
   local card_id = table.remove(card_ids)

   if card_id == seen_card_id then
      local i = math.random(1, #card_ids)
      card_ids[i], card_id = card_id, card_ids[i]
   end

   -- Deal the specific card.
   deck.takeObject({
      guid     = card_ids[i],
      position = player.getHandTransform().position,
      flip     = true,
   })
end
```

When we pick the card the player has already seen, it is placed back at a random location among the remaining cards. This ensures that every card has an equal chance of being drawn by the next player. This is the underlying principle of the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

---

Full demonstration

```lua
function broadcast_error(msg)
   broadcastToAll(msg, { r=1, g=0, b=0 })
end


function get_cards_seen_by_players()
   local player_ids = Player.getAvailableColors()

   local error = false
   local seen_card_by_player = {}
   for i, player_id in ipairs(player_ids) do
      local player = Player[player_id]
      local hand_objs = player.getHandObjects()
      local player_error = false
      if #hand_objs > 1 then
         player_error = true
      elseif #hand_objs == 1 then
         local card = hand_objs[1]
         if card.tag ~= "Card" then
            player_error = true
         else
            seen_card_by_player[player] = card
         end
      end

      if player_error then
         broadcast_error(player_id .. " doesn't have a valid hand.")
         error = true
      end
   end

   if error then
      return nil
   end

   return seen_card_by_player
end


function run()
   local deck = getObjectFromGUID("...")

   local seen_card_by_player = get_cards_seen_by_players()
   if seen_card_by_player == nil or next(seen_card_by_player) == nil then
      return
   end

   local seen_card_id_by_player = {}
   for player, card in pairs(seen_card_by_player) do
      local card_id = card.guid
      seen_card_id_by_player[player] = card_id
      card.putObject(deck)
   end

   deck.randomize()

   local card_ids = {}
   for i, card_data in ipairs(deck.getObjects()) do
      table.insert(card_ids, card_data.guid)
   end

   for player, seen_card_id in pairs(seen_card_id_by_player) do
      local card_id = table.remove(card_ids)

      if card_id == seen_card_id then
         local i = math.random(1, #card_ids)
         card_ids[i], card_id = card_id, card_ids[i]
      end

      deck.takeObject({
         guid     = card_ids[i],
         position = player.getHandTransform().position,
         flip     = true,
      })
   end
end
```

Create a game with a deck of cards. Place the above code in Global, replacing `...` with the deck's GUID. To run the demonstration, deal one card to any number of players, then use `/execute Global.call("run")` in the chat window.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I will try this out later. At the moment I do a simple Fisher-Yates shuffle, check to make sure each card doesn't match a players existing card, if it fails it does another Fisher-Yates shuffle, while loops until there isn't a single match in the shuffle from the original. I was hoping that I would be able to do it without a while loop and just 1 run where I could get a definitive big O and not randomness.

Comment: The solution is I provided is O(N). If you have a list of ids of every card, and if `deck.takeObject` is O(1), then an O(1) solution is possible. (Instead of `deck.randomize()`, you'd do one or two passes of a FYS per player, depending on whether they saw their own card or not.) But I doubt that `deck.takeObject` is O(1)

Comment: But even a brute force, reshuffle until everything is ok approach is statistically O(N). As you increase the number of cards, the chance of needing a shuffle become exceedingly close to zero. With a large deck size (and a small number of players), needing 3 shuffles is never going to be needed, so we could say it's bound by O(3N), which is just O(N).

Comment: I accepted your answer but I went with a different much simpler method. While making this I realized I wanted only 1 chain. So that we can make a single chain of cards and not have 2 players swap cards and create a separate chain. So what I did was I shuffled a table with the players colors and inside an ipair foreach I did PlayersCards[i]["SecondCard"] = PlayerCards[i+1]["FirstCard"]. If course I did a modulus check so that it goes back to 1 if it is greater then the players size.